# Grep search for 'x' number of words in a sentence

Tags: grep

I searched everywhere before crowding this community with this -- what I thought would be a simple task. Given a list of sentences in a txt file I am trying to get the command to search for sentences with 'x' number of words. In my particular case it is 4.
I have tried:

```
egrep [A-Za-z]{4} file.txt
egrep -m 4 [A-Za-z] file.txt
egrep [[:alpha:]]{4} file.txt
```

Any insight is appreciated and thank you.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please read the description of the tags you apply, the "linux" tag doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of "words" and "sentences" is very fuzzy, but it sounds like you might do well to start with this.

```
egrep -i '[a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+' file.txt
```

Each `[a-z]+` means "one or more letters", and you want four of those separated by spaces. You don't have to specify uppercase letters because the `-i` makes the search case-insensitive.

However, things can get very complicated very soon. How do you define a "word"? If "can't" is a word, then this regex won't work because "can't" won't match `[a-z]+`. What about hyphenated words? etc etc etc.